# Set absolute 3D rotation is Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to show a 3D model of a box that should rotate according to some accelerometer values that are read in real time (down is where gravity is at).

I have the box, I can use `rotate`, but when new values come in I can only rotate relative to the current position of the box with `rotate`. Is there a way to either reset rotation to default values (0, 0, 0) or to set new absolute rotation values in Matlab?

Here's what I've got right now:
[image]

I tried to use the delta between old and new values, but the error gets too big too quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotate` changes the actual data of your object, not just a view on it. Therefore, the only way to 'reset' would be to save the original data used to generate the object, and then re-set those data using calls like

```
set(oh, 'Xdata', origXData)
set(oh, 'Ydata', origYData)
set(oh, 'Zdata', origZData)
```

where `oh` is the handle of the object.

An alternative would be not to use `rotate` but `view`, which does not modify the object but only the viewpoint. However, a call to `view` does not change the viewpoint relative to the current one, but only absolutely. Therefore you'd need to keep track of the current viewpoint in a variable, modify it based on your accelerometer readings, and set the new value.